# Oracle Java and XGBoost4j on Alpine

Tags: java, xgboost, alpine-linux

I am trying to use XGBoost4j (https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/master/jvm-packages) on Alpine Linux, with Oracle Java.

I know anything using glibc should probably not be used on Alpine, but using OpenJDK is not an option in this case as OpenJDK does not play nice with some of my other code.

So, what I have tried is compiling XGBoost4j myself with the same Oracle Java version I have in the Alpine Linux image. I have also added glibc (2.25-r0) to this image as well to get Oracle Java to work. Everything works nicely, but once I try to train a model with XGBoost in this image I get this error:

```
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-lookup.c: 128: check_match: Assertion `version->filename == NULL || ! _dl_name_match_p (version->filename, map)' failed!
```

I searched around for a bit and people said adding libc6-compat might work. But that is incompatible with glibc. So I'm at a loss here. Are there any other Alpine libraries I'm missing that can be helpful, or is this just not doable?